# Webhook call returns recipients with an ID different than the one I sent when building the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Laravel application that sends documents for signature and listens to calls from Docusign Connect every time a signer signs a document.

When building the envelope, I set a custom recipient_id so when Docusign calls the webhook I can figure out which signer to update on my database:

```
        $customer = new Signer([
            'email_notification' => [
                'supported_language' => $document->language->iso,
            ],
            'inherit_email_notification_configuration' => true,
            'recipient_type' => 'signer',
            'email' => $customerSignerEmail,  
            'name' => $customerSignerName,  
            'recipient_id' => 100,  
            'routing_order' => $document->document_type->customer_signing_order,
            'tabs' => $tab_customer,
        ]);
```

However, Docusign Connect always returns recipient_id = 1 for the first signer, recipient_id = 2 for the second one, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior if you're using Composite Templates: Recipient IDs (and document IDs) get renumbered to 1, 2, 3 when the envelope is created.

There are a couple of options to keep track of a particular recipient through an envelope's lifecycle. From: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-how-to-track-recipients-and-documents-when-ids-change

> With recipients, you have an extra option in addition to recipient custom fields: the RoleName parameter. Both recipient custom fields and the RoleName are readily available in the Recipients::List call or in a Envelope::Get call with include=recipients. If you're already referencing a server template, continuing to use the RoleName to identify a particular recipient is likely the simplest way to move forward, but if you need multiple data points or the RoleName isn't right for your use case, you can use recipient custom fields instead.

Comment: Recipient custom fields are particularly useful, as you can use a system-specific identifier so that there is no confusion or ambiguity. For example, if your business system has a customerID that gets generated for every customer contact, then passing the customerID as a Recipient Custom Field on that particular recipient will always uniquely identify that customer, even across multiple envelopes.